# Can't add to directory context menu in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, context-menu

In Windows 8.1 (and probably other versions as well) it was possible to add a program to the shell/context menu of any directory. However applying the method it doesn't seem to work in Windows 10. When adding the key to a file extension it does work though.

What I'm specifically trying to do is opening a folder in sublime from the context menu. I used the same key in Windows 8.1 where it did work. Here is the content of a registry file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Open with Sublime Text]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Open with Sublime Text\command]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Sublime Text 3\\sublime_text.exe \"%V\""
```

Comment: You might try Nirsoft's ShellExView, http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html, which can disable and enable context menu items, and see what changes it makes to the Registry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it should be added under the Background sub-directory. So for completeness is here the working key:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\sublime\command]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Sublime Text 3\\sublime_text.exe \"%V\""
```